# Pagedown Editor - make inline links instead of referenced links

Tags: javascript, markdown, pagedown

Does anyone know how to use hooks or edit `Markdown.Editor.js` from Pagedown to have it create inline links and instead of referenced ones?

As in, I want this to happen when I click the link button:

```
[inline link](http://www.google.com)
![alt text](http://website.com/bear.jpg "title text")
```

instead of this:

```
[referenced link][1]
![referenced image][2]


  [1]: http://google.com/
  [2]: http://website.com/bear.jpg "title text"
```

Thanks!

For reference: https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there do not appear to be any hooks for this functionality in `Markdown.Editor.js`. I was however able to find the section of code responsible for this, and create a patch for your desired functionality.

1. Open [`Markdown.Editor.js`](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Editor.js) in your editor of choice.
2. Find this section of code:

   ```
                   var linkDef = " [999]: " + properlyEncoded(link);

                   var num = that.addLinkDef(chunk, linkDef);
                   chunk.startTag = isImage ? "![" : "[";
                   chunk.endTag = "][" + num + "]";
   ```
3. Replace with this code:

   ```
                   chunk.startTag = isImage ? "![" : "[";
                   chunk.endTag = "](" + properlyEncoded(link) + ")";
   ```
4. Profit!

[image]

Comment: Perfect. It won't let me award the bounty yet, but this works great! Works for both links and images.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a copy
2. Open a file `Markdown.Converter.js`
3. Scroll to the line 724
4. Edit method `function _DoImages(text) {}`
5. Scroll to the line 581
6. Edit method `function _DoAnchors(text) {}`

Finally you can achieve absolutely any imaginable results with editing the source code.

UPD:

Just for fun the patch (if you prefer the patches):

```
converter.hooks.chain("postConversion", function (text) {
    var anchors = [];
    // definitions
    text = text.replace(/\[(\d+)\]\: (htt.+)\n/gi, function(anchor_definition){
         anchors.push(anchor_definition.match(/(htt.+)\n/i)[1]);
         return("");
    });
    // anchors in the text
    text = text.replace(/\]\[\d+\]/gi, function(anchor){
        var id = parseInt(anchor.match(/\d+/)[0]);
        var code = "][" + (anchors[id - 1]) + "]";
            return(code);
    });

    return(text);        
});
```